# How to add watermark to the doxygen generated PDF file

Tags: latex, pdf-generation, doxygen, watermark, pdflatex

I am generating the PDF file using doxygen on a Linux system. 
I am using "make" in the latex folder. This generates the refman.pdf. I want to add a "INTERNAL ONLY" watermark to this. How can I achieve this? Is there a configuration item in the doxygen config file?